# Difficulties with arrays and for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm having difficulties with the `for` loop. The first instance of the first and last name of the student works but the rest of the names are getting the `alert`. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Js Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name"/>
    <input type="name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"/>
    <input type="name" id="result" placeholder="Full Name"/>
    <button onclick='validator()' id="submit">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**js:**

```
var students = [
{first:'Max', last:'Smith'},
{first:'Ardon', last:'Bailey'},
{first:'Todd', last:'Gumke'},
{first:'Bob', last:'Plug'},
{first:'Trub', last:'Lee'}];

function full_name (first_name, last_name) {
var foo = false;
for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    if (students[i].first === first_name && students[i].last === last_name) {
        foo = true;
    }
}
if (foo === true) {
    alert('yay');
} else {
    alert('sad');
 }
}


function validator() {
var result = document.getElementById('result');
result.value = full_name(document.getElementById('first_name').value,  document.getElementById('last_name').value);
}
```

Comment: I see multiple stragne things in the code. Can you exlain briefly on what you are trying to acheive?

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good idea to share your current output and desired output.

Comment: If this is meant to be a search, you probably don't want the alert inside the loop. Also, your `if` statement probably doesn't do what you want. Can you explain what the code is supposed to do?

Comment: I want to type in the the first and last name with the same place value in the array, within the input. If the first and last name don't match up, I want it to go to alert. Hopefully, that's clear. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Also consider embracing JSON: http://jsfiddle.net/UGsN7/

Comment: `i < Math.min(students_first.length,students_last.length)`

Comment: This, while harmless in this case, is odd: `i < (students_first && students_last.length)`. That would really only be useful if you thought `students_first` may be a falsey value instead of an Array. If they're the same length, just do `i < students_first.length`

Comment: ...also, why have parallel arrays in the first place. An Array of Objects would seem more sensible. `[{first:"Max",last:"Smith"}, {first:"Ardon",last:"Bailey"}, ... ]`

Comment: Of if you want to get really fancy take a look at Prototypal Inheritance: http://jsfiddle.net/UGsN7/2/ (passes JSHint now)

Comment: @JasonSperske I plugged in your code and I am still getting errors. I changed the alert so it was an else statement and then alert.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly:

replace this line:

```
if ((first_name && last_name) === (students_first[i] && students_last[i])){
```

with this:

```
if (first_name == students_first[i] && last_name == students_last[i]){
```

and this line:

```
for(i = 0; i < (students_first && students_last.length); i++) {
```

with this:

```
for(i = 0; i < students_first.length && i < students_last.length; i++) {
```

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

`first_name && last_name` is a conditional. I believe you intended for that to be string concatenation.

```
if (first_name + last_name === students_first[i] + students_last[i]){
```

Comment: But if the real names are `abc def` and the user types `abcd` and `ef` , the error won't be showed because `abc+def==abcdf` and  `abcd+ef==abcdf`

Comment: I didn't say the logic was sound, :p